# Rails 3.2.18 application assets not displaying properly on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Ive been given a rails 3.2 app and heroku "server" to work on and deploy to.

I have deployed the application to heroku, and it is being served, but the website is all mumbled up and not displaying css/js properly.  From experience it seems that the assets have not been precompiled.

Below is what I have tried so far to get this to work.

1. I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` on my local, committed the changes, and pushed to heroku.  Page was still not rendering properly.
2. I ran `rake assets:clean` to remove public/assets.  Then deployed to heroku, and watched them be precompiled on the deploy.  This still resulted in the site not displaying properly.
3. Started playing with my `production.rb` file

   `config.cache_classes = true`

   `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

   `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`

   `config.serve_static_assets = false`

   `config.assets.compress = true`

   `config.assets.compile = false`

   `config.assets.digest = true`

   `config.assets.precompile += %w( ie-html5shiv-printshiv.js ie-selectivizr.min.js )`

this still has resulted in my site not displaying correctly.

Im at odds end, not sure what else to try.  Any other tips or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the rails_12factor gem to your gemfile, bundle, commit and push.

*Gemfile.rb*

```
'gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production'
```